# WPF XAML ListBox Circular Scrolling behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scroll, listbox

I have a listbox in wpf xaml and it is binded to the collection of 12 months. This listbox has auto vertical scrolling. I'd like to scroll the list in a circular way, so that when the last item approaches in the visible portion of the listbox, it show the first item next to it and so on (January,....). Similarly, if I scroll upwards then when Januray approaches, December, November should be shown above it.
Furthermore, I want to fix the selected item right in the center of listbox.

```
<ListBox x:Name="Months" MinHeight="280" Height="Auto"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Months, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type datePicker:DatePicker}}}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMonth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type datePicker:DatePicker}}, Mode=TwoWay}"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
         ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}" />
```

I have no idea how to do this in C#, Please help.

I have tried to set the verticaloffset of scrollviewer but then it jumps to the 1st item on the top of list which is not circular scrolling.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like carousel. You can find some WPF carousel examples or try to port [Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.Carousel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/carousel) to WPF.